# ckeditor - using attachinary instead of paperclip/carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, cloudinary

I am currently storing images on Cloudinary using the attachinary gem. I was just wondering if it is possible to swap paperclip/carrierwave out for Attachinary. I had trouble using paperclip due to the imagemagik dependency, and was hoping to stick to Attachinary for saving blog post with images using ckeditor, since Attachinary makes it so trivial to "CRUD" images to and from Cloudinary.

Or maybe someone has a better idea for me. What I'm trying to achieve is a simple way for a user to create a blog post in a rails app. Was hoping to get some sort of WYSIWYG way for the user to write a blog article and insert pictures at certain points in the article. I was thinking something similar to the way stack overflows editor would be nice. It really needs to be simple, just text and attach pictures, and maybe italics bold underline, but I don't really need fonts. Maybe a way for the user to add some quote tags similar to the foundation/bootstrap quotes (I believe it is done with CSS) you see around the web for advertising. Maybe some simple formatting and some lists. Nothing is set in stone unfortunately.

Maybe some insight on this editor for stack overflow would be helpful...I would assume they could totally rearrange the formatting to their liking after the question is stored...